# How can I close this for loop 2d array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop, 2d

I am new to programming I am struggling with how to end this loop.
The teacher is not helping to clarify.

The question  I need to answer is "Ask the user to enter five days of the week and rainfall data for each day. Store the data in a two dimensional string array named rainfallData[]" Thanks so much!

```
        String[,] rainFallData = new String[5, 2];
        String name;
        String rainFall;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of day " + i);
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            rainFallData[i - 1, 0] = name;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter rainFall of day " + i);
            rainFall = Console.ReadLine();

            rainFallData[i - 1, 1] = rainFall;

            for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
```

Comment: When you have 5 sets of data, exit the loop?

Comment: recommend to start for loop with i = 0; and use string instead of String. string[5, 2]; why do you have a second for oop? it seems your code is not complete. What issue are you having with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break`. When you want to end the loop just write `break;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that "closes the loop" by only asking for the info 5 times. It also shows how to write the data from the 2d array to the console after.

```
    String[,] rainFallData = new String[5, 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < rainFallData.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        string name;
        string rainFall;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of day " + i);
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter rainFall of day " + i);
        rainFall = Console.ReadLine();

        rainFallData[i, 0] = name;
        rainFallData[i, 1] = rainFall;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rainFallData.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Weekday: " + rainFallData[i,0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Rainfall: " + rainFallData[i,1]);
    }
```